# MySQL stored procedure syntax

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a very basic stored procedure in MySQL. It has to increment an int value in a table. I also want the stored procedure to be dropped if already exists. The sql inside the stored procedure works fine on its own btw.

I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'END' at line 5

i have tried:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_version_increment$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_version_increment`()
BEGIN
    SET @ver = (SELECT version FROM version LIMIT 1) + 1;
    UPDATE version SET version = @ver
END$$
DELIMITER


DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_version_increment$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_version_increment`()
BEGIN
    SET @ver = (SELECT version FROM version LIMIT 1) + 1;
    UPDATE version SET version = @ver
END
```

SOLUTION:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_version_increment$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_version_increment`()
BEGIN
    SET @num = (SELECT number FROM version LIMIT 1) + 1;
    UPDATE version SET number = @num;
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer myself:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_version_increment$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_version_increment`()
BEGIN
    SET @num = (SELECT number FROM version LIMIT 1) + 1;
    UPDATE version SET number = @num;
END
```

I still have no idea why it wouldnt accept the other queries i made, so if anyone can spare a few words on the subject, i'd be glad :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_version_increment;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_version_increment`()
BEGIN
    SET @ver = (SELECT version FROM version LIMIT 1) + 1;
    UPDATE version SET version = @ver;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_version_increment;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_version_increment`()
BEGIN
    SET @ver = (SELECT version FROM version LIMIT 1) + 1;
    UPDATE version SET version = @ver;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I think i just need one of them. The ones i posted above, where just two seperate tries, which failed. i'll try your suggestion immediately

Comment: Doing that gives me this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 6

Comment: please try again I edited my  code and it's can create procedure i test on Mysql Workbench

Comment: That didnt work for me either. I found a solution myself, adding it to mig question in a sec